# how to get url from IFolder

Tags: java, eclipse

i have an object of IFolder type. Iwant to get the complete url of that resource.How can i get it? Help

Comment: Standard JDK up to 1.6u19 does not include the `IFolder` type, so the question is a little ambiguous. You should probably consult javadocs or sources (if available) of whatever library you use.

Comment: @Incarnate IFolder is an Eclipse datatype representing a folder in the workspace of Eclipse.

Comment: Yeap, never developed under Eclipse, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

IResource.getFullpath().toFile().toURL()